# how to wrap a jquery Plugin - jtable.js in a angular directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins

I am trying to wrap jtable in a angularjs directive. But i am not able to run it. its working fine in jquery, Can anybody help me with this?

My html code is:

```
 <jtable></jtable>
```

My Angular code is:

```
  myApp.directive("jtable",function(){
    return
    {
        link: [function(scope, el, attrs) {
            el.jtable({
                title: 'Table of people',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '/GettingStarted/PersonList',
                    createAction: '/GettingStarted/CreatePerson',
                    updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
                    deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'
                },
                fields: {
                    PersonId: {
                        key: true,
                        list: false
                    },
                    Name: {
                        title: 'Author Name',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    Age: {
                        title: 'Age',
                        width: '20%'
                    },
                    RecordDate: {
                        title: 'Record date',
                        width: '30%',
                        type: 'date',
                        create: false,
                        edit: false
                    }
                }
            });
            (angular.element(el)).pluginActivationFunction(scope.$eval(attrs.jtable));
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use restrictions in your directives like :

restrict: 'ACEM',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)

And u have to in view like as a any one attribute,elemement,class and comment or model

Answer (score 0):

you have to use restrictions in your directives like :

```
  restrict: 'ACEM', 
  link: function (scope, element, attrs)
```

And you have to add in view like as a any one attribute,elemement,class and comment or model:

```
 <div id="jtableConfiguration" style="margin-top:40px;" jtable-Configuration> </div>
```

Here "jtableConfiguration" directive name.